# Detecting variable change as soon as possible

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, thread-synchronization

First of all, this has to do with homework. Just a little hint would be enough.

What I have to do is to detect when a variable(signal) has changed and announce it in 1 microsecond or less. My progress so far:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;

  N = atoi(argv[1]);

  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s N\n"
           " where\n"
           " N    : number of signals to monitor\n"
       , argv[0]);

    return (1);
  }

  // set a timed signal to terminate the program
  signal(SIGALRM, exitfunc);
  alarm(20); // after 20 sec

  // Allocate signal, time-stamp arrays and thread handles
  signalArray = (int *) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
  timeStamp = (struct timeval *) malloc(N*sizeof(struct timeval));

  pthread_t sigGen;
  pthread_t *sigDet = (pthread_t*) malloc(N * sizeof(pthread_t));

  long *signalid = (long*) malloc(N * sizeof(long));

  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    signalArray[i] = 0;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
      signalid[i] = (long) i;
      pthread_create (&sigDet[i], NULL, ChangeDetector, (void*) signalid[i]);
  }
  pthread_create (&sigGen, NULL, SensorSignalReader, NULL);

  // wait here until the signal
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
        pthread_join (sigDet[i], NULL);
  }
  return 0;
} 

void *SensorSignalReader (void *arg)
{

  char buffer[30];
  struct timeval tv;
  time_t curtime;

  srand(time(NULL));

  while (1) {
    int t = rand() % 10 + 1; // wait up to 1 sec in 10ths
    usleep(t*100000);

    int r = rand() % N;
    signalArray[r] ^= 1;

    if (signalArray[r]) {
      gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
      timeStamp[r] = tv;
      curtime = tv.tv_sec;
      strftime(buffer,30,"%d-%m-%Y  %T.",localtime(&curtime));
      printf("Changed %5d at Time %s%ld\n",r,buffer,tv.tv_usec);
    }
  }
}

void *ChangeDetector (void *arg)
{
  char buffer[30];
  struct timeval tv;
  time_t curtime;
  long n = (long) arg;

  while (1) {

    while (signalArray[n] == 0) {}

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    curtime = tv.tv_sec;
    strftime(buffer,30,"%d-%m-%Y  %T.",localtime(&curtime));
    printf("Detcted %5ld at Time %s%ld after %ld.%06ld sec\n", n, buffer,tv.tv_usec,
       tv.tv_sec - timeStamp[n].tv_sec,
       tv.tv_usec - timeStamp[n].tv_usec);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    while (signalArray[n] == 1) {}

  }
}
```

With this implementation my program achieves to detect up to 3 signals in time <= 1 us. When more than 3 the response delay up to few ms. How could I detect even more signals in that time? I was wondering how thread tasks are allocated in CPU cores? I've read that it's too painful to manage what is executed on each core by code? Would I earn something with that effort?

Comment: Getting the time of day *before* locking the mutex would be an obvious improvement, but access to your `signalArray` is horribly unsynchronized to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ChangeDetector()` relies on busy-waiting on the flag.  The problem is that you can't have more processes simultaneously busy-waiting than you have CPUs - only some subset of your `ChangeDetector()` processes are actually going to be running at any point in time.

This means that quite often, you have to wait for the right `ChangeDetector` thread to be scheduled back onto the CPU before it can run and notice that the flag has changed.

If you want to have one `ChangeDetector` thread for every flag, then you will need to use a non-busy-waiting method, like pthread condition variables (you can have one mutex / condition variable pair per flag).  I am not sure if you will be able to get sub-microsecond latency this way, though.

If you want really want to stick with the busy-waiting method, you'll need to limit your number of `ChangeDetector` threads to less than the number of CPUs, by having each thread responsible for checking multiple array locations in every loop.